# Unable to install Intel® HAXM HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac. Please file a bug against Android Studio

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to install the intel haxm but I see this error :  Unable to install Intel® HAXM
HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac.
Please file a bug against Android Studio.

I am trying to set the android studio emulator in visual studio for react native. But i cant set install first intel

Answer (score 0):

After too much Google and research I found to install HAXM from external other then Android Studio Use browser and go the below URl  Dowload the setup file of HAXm and run the installation
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases